# iOS CoreLocation, Determine user leaving a location

Tags: ios, core-location

I've been working in a iOS location tracking application, and we've found a way to determine when users are leaving a place, but we're doing it by constantly listening to location updates, which ends draining our battery.

What is the most efficient way to do a thing like this? i would like to get a battery consumption similar to the reminders application.

Any idea is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the desiredAccuracy property

Answer (score 1):

You should set up your app to use geofences.

The method you want to look at is the CLLocationManager method `startMonitoringForRegion`. You need to set up your app to ask the user for permission to monitor location updates.

The system will launch your app to deliver a region update if it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "leaving a place". But you can use

```
func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

On CLLocationManager in order to be notified (roughly) when the user moves 500 meters or more, [according to Apple documention.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)

This shifts the responsibility of watching battery life over to Apple's code, which as you might imagine is well optimized for the task.

Answer (score -1):

Follow @rschmidt's function for starting location update on device.
Track user's current locality by keeping a variable named 'currentLocality' in the class which is delegating `CLLocationManager`.

Implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in the following way

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var currentLocation = locations.last as? CLLocation

    // Getting current locality with GeoCoder
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                    let placeMark = placemarks.last as? CLPlacemark
                    if let latestLocality = placeMark!.locality {
                      if latestLocality != currentLocality {
                        // Locality has been changed, do necessary actions

                        // Updating current locality
                        currentLocality = latestLocality
                      }

                    }
            }
        })

}
```